# Loading server image using initWithData not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using following code to display image from server in UIImageView.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gettyicons.com/free-icons/125/miscellaneous/png/256/apple_256.png"];

NSData *imageData =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
imgLargePicture.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

I can see the picture in Saffari but the image is not rendered in the iPhone application. I searched a lot on net and even in stackoverflow, everywhere this same code is given to display image from server. But in my case somehow its not working.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: do an log on imageData, NSLog(@"ImageDataLenght:%d",[imageData length]). If you have bytes the problem is form your image view. Paste  the code for it here.

Comment: You should not download images on UI thread you should crete a new thread to do this. Or use some library to download asynchronous the image.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint after imgLargePicture.image = [[... ]] statement. What does it show? A null pointer? Or an allocated address? If an address is allocated, you probably did not add the imageView as a subview to your main view.

Comment: @Terente - It shows the imageData length as 4118 that means data is downloaded. I have created ImageView in xib file and an outlet in viewcontroller. imgLargePicture is the name of IBoutlet. The same code works if I load image using imageNamed that means ImageView is not an issue.  Regarding asynchronous thing as I am new to iPhone programming I thought of first implementing it in simple way and then will do it in asynchronous manner.

Comment: @Ravi - It shows a allocated address. I have also added it as subview to my view. If I just replace the code of getting image from server to getting image from application (using imageNamed) everything works fine.

Comment: @Terente - One more update I have downloaded a code sample from apple.com "http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/URLCache/Introduction/Intro.html" and this application also does not show any image. Are there any setting in XCode which I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because of proxy server setup in the organization. It required me to provide user name & password to go through proxy. So this is fixed by implementing AuthenticationChallenge method where I passed the credentials.

Comment: Give code in your answer that how you have passed detail. That is proper way to give answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried that code in my app and it worked. You are not adding that "imgLargePicture" (I assume it's a UIImageView) as your UIViewController's view subview or not giving it a proper frame.
Try this in your `-viewDidLoad:` and see if it works

```
UIImageView *imgLargePicture = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:imgLargePicture];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gettyicons.com/free-icons/125/miscellaneous/png/256/apple_256.png"];

NSData *imageData =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
imgLargePicture.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I copied the code mentioned by you in my application but it is also not working. But if I replace the same code by loading image using [UIImage imageName:@"someImage.png"] everything works. I checked in debugger and I can see some value in NSData that means image is downloaded from the server but somehow not getting displayed. Is there anything else that I can check?

Answer (score 0):

I use the same code of you and i get the image, so please check the NSData and make sure that imageView IBOutlet should be properly connected. Same code is running fine at my side i have check in xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the IBOutlet and it is properly configured. To check that I replaced the above code by loading image with name and in that case image displays properly.